# Intelij: Cannot import classes from other modules in my project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, import, package

My Application consists of multiple `Java` modules, built with `Gradle`.

I have created a new module within it and I cannot import any classes from the *other modules*. I am quite new to Gradle/Java so perhaps Im missing something very obvious.

When I attempt to import a class I get the following error:

```
"Cannot resolve symbol [import class name]"
```

What can I do to resolve this? Do I need to alter my `build.gradle` scripts? Could it be my `package structure`?

Note: I *am* able to import standard java libraries, such as

```
java.util.HashMap
```

My Build.gradle is just the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make an import one module into another, you have to provide a module dependencies in your build script. You can read about it in the official documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html).

All you need to do, is to provide defined project structure with the settings.gradle file in the root. And then add the dependencies section to the module, in which you need to import something, like:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shared')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add this as a dependency. So this should be added in the build.gradle and also my new module added to settings.gradle?

Comment: Yes, you can use another project as dependency, only if this projects have the same root project, so the should be declared in settings.gradle file. And the exact dependency should be added to the build.gradle file